# How to resize an UITabBar selection indicator image in landscape

Tags: ios, uiimage, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I'm customizing a `UITabBar` in a `UITabBarController` subclass ("CustomTabBarVC"). I wanted to use a custom selection indicator image, so I wrote this in the "CustomTabBarVC" implementation:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
   CGFloat tabItemWidth;
   UIView *tabItem = [[[self.tabBar items] lastObject] view];
   tabItemWidth = tabItem.frame.size.width;

   UIImage *selectionIndicator;

   // Set here 'selectionIndicator' to an UIImage which fits 'tabItemWidth' and tab bar's height

   [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:selectionIndicator];
}
```

This works fine when the view is loaded in portrait, but when I change the orientation of the device to landscape, though the method is called again and `selectionIndicator` image seems to take the new width, it is no redrawn and the previous image keeps showing. How could I handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When your device orientation get changed, the default delegate will get called and you get your orientation in this method.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
 // do something before rotation 
}
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
 // do something after rotation
}
```

Then implement viewWillAppear: and this method will get called after the orientation delegate. Now you can change your TabBar image in this method.